# PyQt4 match list of strings with QRegExp

Tags: python, regex, qt, pyqt, qregexp

I am trying to filter a QSortFilterProxyModel with a QRegExp to match any of a list of strings.  The issue is that the strings contain special characters like: `(`, `)`, `\`, `/`, `?`, `,`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `:`, `|`, `.`, `*`, etc..

This means I can't use something like:

`r'\b(' + '|'.join(string_list) + r')\b'`

I have tried subclassing QSortFilterProxyModel's filterAcceptsRow to check against the list of strings with something like:

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
    index = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
    item = self.sourceModel().itemFromIndex(index)
    text = item.text()
    if text in self.matchList:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which works, but is extremeley slow compared to this: (I know this is only matching one word and not a list, but I am hoping that a list implemented properly with regex will be faster than the code above.)

```
self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(QtCore.QRegExp(item.text(), QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString))
self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(3)
```

Is there any way to get QRegExp to take a list of strings or qstrings or a qstringlist to match against?  Is there a way to write a regex that will escape any special characters coming into it automatically?  What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: [QRegExp.escape](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#escape).

Comment: Thank you, I had not come across that in my searches.  I'd select this as a correct answer.

Comment: `itemFromIndex` may be the problem. You can get text at index with `index.data().toString()`. Note that the last `if` block can be rewritten as `return text in self.matchList`.